# How can we know that the user clicked the save button in calendar to create an event or the cancel button?

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
                        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,desc )
                        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, loc)
                        .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
```

I used this code for adding event.I don't want to use insertion using ContentValues because it will not give the user a chance to select his calendar.So how can i know that user has pressed the save or cancel button?PLZZZZZZ HELP

```
startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_CANCELED);
```

As per your suggestions I used this to start the calendar activity and below is my onActivityResult callback.

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int req,int res,Intent intent){

                if(RESULT_OK==res){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resuming Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Created Event number:"+String.valueOf(getLastEventID()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                addReminder(getLastEventID());
                }
                else if(RESULT_CANCELED==res){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No events added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             }
```

Now the problem is that on pressing DONE or CANCEL,both the times Toast appears showing "No events added".This means that DONE and CANCEL returns RESULT_CANCELED.Please check it....

Comment: Did you check to see what the result is in your onActivityResult callback? The standard is to return RESULT_CANCELED if it's been canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
         //XXXXXXXX
    } else if (RESULT_CANCELED == resultCode){
         //XXXXXXXX
    }
}
```